# What is the use of clothing in candy box the first game?

Tags: candy-box

I have acquired a few pieces of clothing and I have no idea of their uses. I would like to know them if they have any. I have the hat, the boots, and the amulet. I don't know if they can help me in any way shape or form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all inventory items description on the [wiki](http://www.candyboxwiki.com/wiki/Inventory).

- The **hat** allows you to purchase the Imp Invocation scroll and the Earthquake scroll
- The **boots** increase your speed during quests
- The **amulet** will multiply by three your candies production
- The **ring** makes you recover 2x as fast after a quest
- The **armor** protects you for 3 hp per hit

All the items you find in the game are helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much, but the wiki for me is blocked would you mind telling me what all the clothing items do?

Comment: @Candyboxplayer Done !